# How to create Loopback model with random string as primary key?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

### TL; DR

How to make `Accounts.create({ provider: "facebook" })` create the `id` primary key automatically?

### Description

Given a persistent Loopback model definition

```
{
  "name": "Account",
  "plural": "accounts",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "id": true,
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "provider": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

how it would be possible add a remote method at `Account.js` to automatically create a random string as primary key?

Comment: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/292

Answer (score 2):

try adding this as a property within the json file of the model:

```
"id": {
  "type": "string",
  "id": true,
  "defaultFn": "uuid"
},
```

This should auto-generate random Primary key as uuid.

Comment: I need to create my own custom UUID function, so I would like to know how to create my own `defaultFn` for ID creation.

Comment: Take a look at uuid - npm module. Should be able to assign that id variable to auto-generated uuid with this module.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on a new instance creation in a `before save` operation hook:

```
Model.observe('before save', (ctx, next) => {

    // If not acting on an instance or property already set, continue.
    if (!ctx.instance || ctx.instance.id) {
        return next();
    }

    ctx.instance.id = uuid();

    next();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

set

```
"idInjection": true,
```

and add

```
"id": {
  "type": "string",
  "id": true,
  "defaultFn": "uuid"
},
```